# Visually see activity from IIS logs on a per visit basis?

Tags: iis-7.5

This is in IIS 7.5 and I'm trying to find a way to see what pages are visited on a per user basis based on the logs.

I used to be able to do this using Whoson, but when making changes to the website a few years ago it seems the visits haven't been picked up correctly - whoops.

I know I can see general statistics using something like Log parser studio, but I'm after an easier solution to say see all pages visited by this ip on this day. Maybe there is a query I'm just missing?

Maybe this isn't possible without specific tagging, but I could have sworn I have done it before... many, many years ago.

Comment: The question is too vague. Please specify the time period, number of pages, and exact names. If you have the exact names, then using grep to search the logs should be possible. In my humble opinion, that is possible to use grep unique and wc mostly

Answer (score 0):

You could use Microsoft PowerBI for this

https://joymonscode.blogspot.com/2019/09/power-bi-desktop-dashboard-for-iis-log.html

Comment: It seems that page is empty